# how to find the alternative method of deprecated method in java?

Tags: java, deprecated

How to  find the  alternative method easily? Some method even moved to another class, It really hard for us when you want to learn from a sample code.

update for the comments: 
Where to find the suggestion? Here is a example: [apache SSLSocketFactory](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER), But I cannot the the solution.

Comment: There is no standard way. Usually, a developer who marks something as deprecated also documents what to use instead.

Comment: Any decent documentation will point you to the new way of doing things. You need to look there.

Comment: hi @npinti, Update my question

Comment: Hi @Seelenvirtuose,  Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSLSocketFactory class has an alternative that is org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory

Deprecated. 
(4.3) use SSLConnectionSocketFactory.

This is first line they gave an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For poorly-documented Java classes, which seem to be the kind that you're dealing with, your best bet is to simply Google the class name, with the `deprecated` keyword, to see what other developers are using instead.

Also, if you prod the developers of the class nicely, they might update their docs, so that you and the rest of the community can benefit. You can make a difference--your email might just be that one additional request or gripe that pushes them to make a move!